# Is this the connected sum of $g$ torus?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

This is a continuation of this post: [Why is this manifold a compact and connected one? Is this a "generalization" of $n$-torus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3863783/why-is-this-manifold-a-compact-and-connected-one-is-this-a-generalization-of)

In the post above, we successfully finished the following exercise:

> Let $g>1$, and consider the polynomial in $x$ with degree $2g$, defined as $$P_g(x) = x(x-1)^2 \cdots (x-g+1)^2 (x-g).  $$ Prove that: $$ M_{g,r} := \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \vert (y^2+P_g(x))^2 + z^2 = r^2 \}$$ is a compact, connected, embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ for sufficiently small $r>0$.

Here my question is: **Is $M_{g,r}$ the connected sum of $g$ torus?** Here the torus means the manifold $\mathbb{T}^2 := S^1 \times S^1$.

I have tried to draw plots with the wolfram alpha and it seems that this is indeed true. But how can I prove (or disprove) this?

If my wild guess is indeed correct, then we can use this to show that the manifold is connected, and actually obtained that the connected sum of $g$ torus is an embedded manifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Thank you all for focusing on this post! :)